# Request Failed Asi HTTP

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, encryption, aes

I am using AES encryption algorithm(ECB) & using ASI http library but my request has been failed due to 401 unauthorised.
I have attached my code below.

Encryption Algo.(AES 128 Encryption)

```
+ (NSData*)encryptData:(NSData*)data key:(NSData*)key iv:(NSData*)iv;
{
    NSData* result = nil;

    // setup key
    unsigned char cKey[FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];
    bzero(cKey, sizeof(cKey));
    [key getBytes:cKey length:FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];

    // setup iv
    char cIv[FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
    bzero(cIv, FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE);
    if (iv) {
        [iv getBytes:cIv length:FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
    }

    // setup output buffer
    size_t bufferSize = [data length] + FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    // do encrypt
    size_t encryptedSize = 0;

//  /  CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus2 = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, [data bytes], [data length], NULL, [cipherData bytes], outLength, [decodedData mutableBytes], [decodedData length], &outLength);

    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                          FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM,
                                           kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          cKey,
                                          FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE,
                                          cIv,
                                          [data bytes],
                                          [data length],
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &encryptedSize);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:encryptedSize];
    } else {
        free(buffer);
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to encrypt|CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Decryption Algo.(AES 128 Decryption)

```
+ (NSData*)decryptData:(NSData*)data key:(NSData*)key iv:(NSData*)iv;
{
    NSData* result = nil;

    // setup key
    unsigned char cKey[FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];
    bzero(cKey, sizeof(cKey));
    [key getBytes:cKey length:FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];

    // setup iv
    char cIv[FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
    bzero(cIv, FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE);
    if (iv) {
        [iv getBytes:cIv length:FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
    }

    // setup output buffer
    size_t bufferSize = [data length] + FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    // do decrypt
    size_t decryptedSize = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                          FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM,
                                           kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          cKey,
                                          FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE,
                                          cIv,
                                          [data bytes],
                                          [data length],
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &decryptedSize);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:decryptedSize];
    } else {
        free(buffer);
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to decrypt| CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Base 64 algo.

```
- (NSString *)base64EncodedString
{
    size_t outputLength;
    char *outputBuffer =
        NewBase64Encode([self bytes], [self length], true, &outputLength);

    NSString *result =
        [[[NSString alloc]
            initWithBytes:outputBuffer
            length:outputLength
            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
        autorelease];
    free(outputBuffer);
    return result;
}
```

Please do needful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What makes you think the problem is encryption? Where are the hex dumps of the key, data in and out? ECB is really not secure especially for images but have code setting up an iv. Why are you using ASI when even the author suggest not using it, AFNetworking is current and being actively maintained. Why are you using 3rd party Base64  code when it is supplied by Apple? Why aren't you using ARC?

Comment: I guess most of the question can be answered by the choice of 3rd party projects chosen, choose better, more current. RNCryptor is current and may fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for you response but there has been implemented ECB at php side so i can not use CBC otherwise php sever can not decrypt my request.

Comment: Due to unicodes my request has been failed so is there any alternate to implement ECB for RNCryptor?

Comment: Encryption is data based, you convert a string to data and encrypt/decrypt the data and then convert back to any format needed.

Comment: To see how bad ECB can be see: [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), scroll down to the penguin picture.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic encrypt/decrypt method. The key must be the correct length. The value context is either `kCCEncrypt` or `kCCDcrypt`.

Convert string to data and encrypt/decrypt the data and then convert back to any format needed. For Base64 encoding use the methods provided by `NSData`.

In the question PKCS7Padding was used in encryption but not in decryption, it needs to be the same in both.

```
+ (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)dataIn
                 key:(NSData *)symmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt
               error:(NSError **)error
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt( encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                       symmetricKey.bytes, 
                       kCCKeySizeAES128,
                       nil,
                       dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length,
                       dataOut.mutableBytes, dataOut.length,
                       &cryptBytes);

    if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
    }
    else {
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kEncryptionError" code:ccStatus userInfo:nil];
        }
        dataOut = nil;
    }
    return dataOut;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your method but Still same response request has been failed :(

Comment: Got this. Status Code : 401 , Status Message : HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Comment: You need to really examine the API, exactly what is required.

Comment: I think there might be problem at server side API.